# copying pointer to a structure in a structure

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I am working with the library libusb which is working nicely, but now I am trying to use its structures in a structure of my own. I think the problem is just the way I copy the structures, so there is probably no need to understand how libusb works.
I have my structure containing libusb structures:

```
struct device {
  libusb_device *device_handled;
  libusb_device_handle *handle;
  int port[7];
};
typedef struct device device;
```

and my function:

```
int myfunction(device *device_element)
{
    libusb_device *tempdevice;
    libusb_device_handle *temphandle;
    device_element = malloc(sizeof(device));

    //my code here where I use tempdevice and temphandle

    (&device_element)->device_handled = tempdevice;
    (&device_element)->handle = temphandle;
}
```

The error issued come from the two last lines and I don't really understand why.

```
‘device_element’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?
     (&device_element)->handle = temphandle;
                      ^~
                      ->
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to add `&` before `device_element` because `malloc` returns a pointer to the allocated structure. So just use:

```
(device_element)->device_handled = tempdevice;  
(device_element)->handle = temphandle;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `&` operator there.

Just use

```
device_element->device_handled = tempdevice;
device_element->handle = temphandle;
```

Comment: It cause a segfault....  Memory is allocated for device_element but is there a need to allocate memory for the libusb_device structure and the libusb_device_handle inside the device structure?

Comment: @wispy No, not really. You may need to post a [mre] is you have other issues.